# Give a direct proof of the fact that $a^2-5a+6$ is even for any $a \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Give a direct proof of the fact that $a^2-5a+6$ is even for any $a \in \mathbb Z.$

I know this is true because any even number that is squared will be even, is it also true than any even number multiplied by 5 will be even?? is this direct proof enough?

Comment: i suggest you to check the question again..

Comment: Your argument doesn't account for odd integers.

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic, i.e. how to compute modulo $m?$ (here $m = 2$, i.e. parity).

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Rewrite it as a product of two consecutive integers (one of which must be even).

Answer (score 8):

$$a^2 - 5a + 6 = (a-2)(a-3) = (a-3)((a-3)+1)$$

Now can you show that one of the two factors must be even? (It would be a good exercise to establish to your satisfaction that given any two *consecutive* integers, exactly one of them is even.)

Sketch of proof by cases : either $a$ is odd, or $a$ is even:

- If $a$  is odd, then $(a-3)$ is even.
- If $a$ is even, then $(a-2)$ is even.

Since one of the factors in $(a-2)(a-3)$ is necessarily even, whatever the value of $a$, the entire product must be even.

Answer (score 3):

By Fermat's little theorem, $a^2\equiv a\pmod{2}$; so
$$
a^2-5a+6\equiv a-a\equiv0\pmod{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$(2n)^2-5(2n)+6=4n^2-10n+6$

$(2n+1)^2-5(2n+1)+6=4n^2-6n$

Do i have to say something more?

Comment: yes, you have to add ${}=2(2n^2-5n+3)$ in the first line, and something similar in the second.

Comment: @GEdgar : I am sure that can be done be completed OP...

Answer (score 1):

This probably goes into more detail than is needed, but here it is.

**$a$ is even:** If $a$ is even, then $a = 2m$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have
$$
(2m)^2-5(2m)+6 = 4m^2-10m+6=2(2m^2-5m+3).
$$
Let $\eta = 2m^2-5m+3$, where $\eta \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $a^2-5a+6$ is even when $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ is even.

**$a$ is odd:** If $a$ is odd, then $a = 2m-1$, where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have
$$
(2m-1)^2-5(2m-1)+6=4m^2-4m+1-10m+5+6=2(2m^2-7m+6).
$$
Let $\gamma = 2m^2-7m+6$, where $\gamma\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $a^2-5a+6$ is even when $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ is odd.

Hence, $a^2-5a+6$ is even when $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ is either even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by "direct proof" they mean "not by contradiction." Such a proof would start out something like "Suppose $a^2 - 5a + 6$ is odd." A direct proof, on the other hand, doesn't set up false assumptions to knock down later.

This is the way I'd go about a direct proof:

If $a$ is odd, then so is $a^2$. The difference between two odd numbers is an even number. Thus $a^2 - 5a$ is even. When you add an even number to an even number, you get another even number. So $a^2 - 5a + 6$ is even.

But if $a$ is even, then so are $a^2$ and $5a$. The difference between two even numbers is also an even number. Thus $a^2 - 5a$ is even, as well as $a^2 - 5a + 6$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

I want to add to amWhy's hint:

An integer $x$ is even if there exists an integer $m$ so that $x=2m$.

An integer $x$ is odd if there exists an integer $m$ so that $x=2m+1$.

Let $a$ be be even:

$(a-2)(a-3)=(2m-2)(2m-3)=4m^2-6m-4m+6=4m^2-10m+6$
$$=2(2m^2-5m+3)$$

where we let $ \phi =(2m^2-5m+3)$, which is an integer by closure and so we have $2\phi$

This proves that when $a$ is even your entire product is even.  You can make a similar argument for odd numbers. 0 is trivial.  Hope this hint helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'logical' way to prove this, without using modular arithmetic, and without case distinctions.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
\newcommand{\even}[1]{#1\text{ is even}}
$I'm assuming that we can use the following two rules:

\begin{align}
\tag 0 \even{n + m} \;\equiv\; \even n \equiv \even m \\
\tag 1 \even{n \times m} \;\equiv\; \even n \lor \even m \\
\end{align}

Now we simply calculate:

$$\calc
\even{a^2 - 5 \times a + 6}
\calcop={$\ref 0$, two times}
\even{a^2} \;\equiv\; \even{5 \times a} \;\equiv\; \even 6
\calcop={$\ref 1$, two times}
\even a \lor \even a \;\equiv\; \even 5 \lor \even a \;\equiv\; \even 6
\calcop={5 is odd, 6 is even; logic: simplify}
\even a \;\equiv\; \even a
\calcop={logic: simplify}
\true
\endcalc$$

Comment: Technically you *are* using modular arithmetic, i.e. *parity* = arithmetic mod $2.\,$ But some students may know that before they know more general modular arithmetic (congruences).